Hide transfers in solana program transfer rust
Hey i managed to create some proxy for sending spl tokens and sol tokens. However when you go to solscan you can see all of the transfers 
however i saw that it's possible to hide this transfers somehow (https://solscan.io/tx/5BWGVNDwjKKCoxU7RhZDWJ3cHTAjpzZdhVfYnGpYA696ceWKJjyqGv2n87iqmEZw11SnTM5nmu3dbi2vF3ZTGnFC), saw some programs do that but i have no clue how. Could u help me? Maybe zk-proofs are the way, or confidential transfers - the problem is that i don't know how should i implement that in my code.
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::{invoke},
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
};

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let fee_payer_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let from_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let to_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let system_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    // Ensure instruction data is exactly 8 bytes
    if instruction_data.len() != 8 {
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
    }
    let amount = u64::from_le_bytes(instruction_data.try_into().map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?);

    if system_program_info.key == &solana_program::system_program::ID {
        msg!("Transferring native SOL: {}", amount);
        invoke(
            &system_instruction::transfer(
                from_info.key,
                to_info.key,
                amount,
            ),
            &[from_info.clone(), to_info.clone()],
        )?;
        return Ok(());
    } 

    // Handle SPL Token transfer logic
    // Only proceed if there are more accounts in the iterator
    if account_info_iter.len() >= 6 {
        let token_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let associated_token_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let rent_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let mint_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let sender_token_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
        let recipient_token_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

        if recipient_token_account_info.lamports() == 0 {
            msg!("Creating associated token account for recipient");
            invoke(
                &spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
                    fee_payer_info.key,
                    to_info.key,
                    mint_info.key,
                    &spl_token::ID
                ),
                &[
                    fee_payer_info.clone(),
                    to_info.clone(),
                    recipient_token_account_info.clone(),
                    system_program_info.clone(),
                    token_program_info.clone(),
                    associated_token_program_info.clone(),
                    rent_info.clone(),
                ],
            )?;
        }

        msg!("Transferring SPL tokens: {}", amount);
        invoke(
            &spl_token::instruction::transfer(
                &spl_token::ID,
                sender_token_account_info.key,
                recipient_token_account_info.key,
                from_info.key,
                &[],
                amount,
            )?,
            &[
                sender_token_account_info.clone(),
                recipient_token_account_info.clone(),
                from_info.clone(),
            ],
        )?;
    }

    Ok(())
}


That transaction that you linked has no transfers, only calls to SetAuthority. There's no way to hide transfers, unless if you use confidential transfers with SPL Token Extensions or some other ZK system, as you mention.
